# Where to find the ChEMBL21 database in CSV format?

Tags: reference-request, drugs, databases, machine-learning, molecular-design

I come from an artificial intelligence (AI) background (and not from chemistry).
However, my Ph.D. thesis is about Deep Reinforcement Learning for drug design.
From one of the most famous papers in this regard [[1, p. 6](https://doi.org/10.1126/sciadv.aap7885)]:

> The generative network was trained with ~1.5 million structures from the ChEMBL21 database.

I was looking for ChEMBL21 database to begin experimenting with it on my own, but could not find it.
Can anyone provide me with a link to this same database (in CSV format if possible), and maybe some advice to better benefit from?

#### Reference

1. Popova, M.; Isayev, O.; Tropsha, A. Deep Reinforcement Learning for De-Novo Drug Design. *Sci. Adv.* **2018**, 4 (7), eaap7885. DOI: [10.1126/sciadv.aap7885](https://doi.org/10.1126/sciadv.aap7885).

Comment: Contact the author(s).

Comment: Official download links for ChEMBL in various formats are given here: https://chembl.gitbook.io/chembl-interface-documentation/downloads. Be careful with the version number; it appears they are now up to version 29.